# wrong number of arguements clojure

Tags: clojure, first-class-functions, seesaw

I'm building a program that's meant to allow users count either the number of letters or number of words in a string, however when running the program through the cmd, I'm getting a clojure.lang.ArityException, wrong number of args (1) passed to : core/-main/counter--5333

My code is

```
;;Create a GUI which allows user to input a string and to select "word count" or "letter count". When "Start" is clicked pass both the string and either (wordCount [string x]) or (letterCount [string x]) to 
;;declare functions as variables
;;show function that takes functions as parameters
;;show function that returns another function
(ns firstclass.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:use seesaw.core))

(defn -main
  [& args]

(def strInput (input "Please enter a string to be evaluated"))

(def groups (button-group))
(def s (selection groups))

(def letterRadio (radio :text "Letter" :group groups))
(def wordRadio (radio :text "Word" :group groups))

(defn letterCount
  [string]
  (loop [characters string
         a-count 0]
    (if (= (first characters) \a)
      (recur (rest characters) (inc a-count))
      a-count)))

(defn wordCount
  [string]
  (loop [characters string
         a-count 0]
    (if (= (first characters) \a)
      (recur (rest characters) (inc a-count))
      a-count)))

(def counter (fn [fn x, string strInput] (x [strInput])))

(defn handler [event]
    (if-let [s letterRadio]
        (counter [letterCount, strInput]))
    (if-let [s wordRadio]
        (counter [wordCount, strInput])))

(def start (button :text "Start Count" :listen [:action handler] ))

(def panel
  (flow-panel :items [strInput, letterRadio, wordRadio, start]))

(invoke-later
  (-> (frame :content panel :on-close :dispose) 
      pack! show!)))
```

Answer (score 2):

for your definition of `counter`

```
(def counter (fn [fn x, string strInput] (x [strInput])))
```

you have a function of four arguments

in the `handler` function, you call it with one argument:

```
(counter [letterCount strInput])
```

from context I assume that you meant to define counter as having two arguments, and you meant to call it on two arguments, rather than a single vector of two items.

```
(def counter (fn [x strInput] (x strInput)))

...

(counter letterCount strInput)
```

Also, it's better to use `defn` to define functions, rather than `def` and `fn` separately

```
(defn counter [x strInput] (x strInput))
```